# Weird SQL request with unknown field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a weird result for SQL request, i gave in my subrequest an unknown field "alert_event_load_time" for "alerts" table, but exists on "alert_events" table, but instead of an error, i have a result :

```
"select count(*) FROM rc.alert_events WHERE 
alert_id in 
(select alert_id from rc.alerts where alert_event_load_time like '2015-08-04%');"

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   237634 |
+----------+
```

And it returns me the same result as the request :

```
select count(*) FROM rc.alert_events WHERE alert_event_load_time like '2015-08-04%' ;"

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   237634 |
+----------+
```

Could it be a bug ?

Comment: how about changing `alert_event_load_time` to any `random_name_you_want` and see what happens ?

Comment: Are you saying that field alert_event_load_time does not exist in table rc.alert_events?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's put in some table aliases.  You think the query is:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM rc.alert_events ae
WHERE ae.alert_id in (select a.alert_id from rc.alerts a
                      where a.alert_event_load_time like '2015-08-04%')
```

However, `alerts.alert_event_load_time` doesn't exist.  So, SQL (in general) looks in the next outer scope to resolve the column alias.  And it finds it.  So, the query is:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM rc.alert_events ae
WHERE ae.alert_id in (select a.alert_id from rc.alerts a
                      where ae.alert_event_load_time like '2015-08-04%')
```

No error, but you still get a result set.

This use of scoping is considered a "feature" of the SQL language.  My recommendation is to never use this feature.  *Always* use table aliases and qualified column names (okay, if there is only one table in the query, then you can relax a bit).

Comment: So, SQL will not take in account the parenthesis for my subRequest ? Do you know if this "feature" is specific to MySQL, or in SQL in general ?

Comment: @toshiro92 . . . This is ANSI standard behavior.  The parentheses simply define the subquery.